# How to include sources generated by jaxb in spring-boot repackage plugin phase?

Tags: java, spring-boot, pom.xml, executable-jar, generated-code

I am currently developing a spring boot app where I have resources being generated by JAXB and I want to repackage a jar with those files. I have tried multiple approaches with the includes tag in configuration area but they all fail.

I have a very common project structure, all I want is repackage to have compiled sources + target/generated-sources/xjc/ stuff.

Here is the example of what I tried

```
<plugin>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>repackage</goal>
                    </goals>
                    <configuration>
                        <outputDirectory>${project.artifactId}/exec</outputDirectory>
                        <includes>
                            <include>my.com.class</include>
                        </includes>
                    </configuration>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
```

What I want is to have my jaxb2 auto generated classes to be included in this jar, but nothing else, like properties etc.